# Many-To-Many relationship in EF with a datafield in the Association table

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have three tables arranged to make a many to many relationship (Contacts, PurchaseOrder, and PO_Contact).  The PurchaseOrder table will eventually represent each purchaseorder (only one instance of each).  Each Customer can be associated with any number of PurchaseOrders and each Purchase Order may be associated with any number of Contacts.  However for each Contact, there can be a Purchase Order that is the Primary PO for that Contact.

I am trying to figure out how I can add this to my EntityModel and I am coming up short.  Eventually I want to have a collection of PO objects with one depicted as the Primary, but I am not sure how to effect that.  Anyone have experience with this?  Please find below the database diagram for the affected tables.

[image: Contact/PO diagram]

[image: Contact/PO EDMX Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue with junction tables is that Entity Framework *does not* have to map them if they contain only the FK's of the adjoining tables, but because you have that **IsPrimary** field, it needs to be represented on the model.

> Eventually I want to have a collection of PO objects with one depicted as the Primary

Yes, as i said above, you're going to have to physically map the PO_Contact table, meaning your queries could end up like this:

```
var contact = db.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactId == 1);
var ordersForContact = contact.PO_Contacts.PurchaseOrders.ToList();
```

and this:

```
var order = db.PurchaseOrders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.POID == 1);
var contactsForOrder = order.PO_Contacts.Contacts.ToList();
```

But to find out "which one is primary"? (and there could be more than one), you'll need another filter.

This could be an example query:

```
var primaryOrdersForConactOne = db.Contacts
                                 .Where(c => c.ContactID == 1)
                                 .Where(c => c.PO_Contacts.IsPrimary)
                                 .ToList();
```

That should work.

*However,* if your positive there could only be one primary order for any given customer, you could setup a form of inheritance (TPH, TPT) and make that field the discriminator, so you end up with seperate "PrimaryOrder" and "SecondaryOrder" entities, deriving from the base "PurchaseOrder" class.

Comment: Well I currently have the conceptual model setup so that Purchase Order appears as an associated entity (Many to Many) with Contact.  In the storage model, I have Contact_PO described.  Is that good as-is, and if so, how would I get at the IsPrimary property, or do I need to describe the Contact_PO table somehow in the conceptual model.  At one point I thought about creating a View of the Contact_PO and PurchaseOrders table and mapping that, but have not gotten to that yet.  Would that be a better course of action?  Will try to post an image of EDMX in original post.

Comment: How did you create that EDMX? Did you generate from DB, or add the entities manually? If you want the IsPrimary field, you'll have to map the junction table. What about moving the IsPrimary field to "Contact" table? Have a field (FK - nullable), called "PrimaryPurchaseOrder". Would that suffice? If you want it on the purchase entity, you'll have to map the junction table.

Comment: Most of the EDMX I created Model-first then generated the DB from it and modified a little afterward.  For the PO and Contact_PO tables I created those tables then added manually.  I think in this case I will go ahead and map the junction table.  I will have to see what form that takes Model-wise.  It may be kind of wierd looking having the PO number hosted in an entity seperate from the Primary boolean.  I may have to make some way to combine them.  ATM I don't know what that will entail however.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do this. If you're writing against a *legacy* database, then you should be generating the model from the DB. If you *dont have* a database, then you should do model-first and try and model your domain correctly. Is this for a brand new app? Have you taken a look at inheritance for your model? (e.g TPH - having seperate entities for Primary/Secondary order). It's still represented as one physical table in the DB, but you can easily find primary orders via the model: `Orders.OfType<PrimaryOrder>()`.

Comment: This is a new application that I am writing against a new SQL2008 database.  This will eventually interact with an ACT! Database (a real mess).  I am trying to keep a table of distinct PO number values (so that interaction with the ACT! DB will go smoother) while allowing for the many-to-many relationship.  I am by no means a DB guru; I am still very much learning.  Essentially, what I want to happen is for Contact info to be synced to the ACT! db (via the primary PO number value through an ACT plugin).  Having a way to define PO records one to one with ACT would be best I think.

Comment: I did some TPH inheritance one some other portions of the model.  I could do that here.  I will have to mull it over.